# Any tool to benchmark web server performance

Tags: untagged

What I wanted to know is if there is any easy tool for me to run in Centos linux to know how good the box is.

Disk IO, CPU, Memory ...not only the data but their performance under high usage, high traffic, high IO operations...

You can tell me tools towards the websites as well. I think that can also test to know if the server as web server is good or bad

Comment: This isn't an answer, just a comment that the very good answers here should specify whether they'll work on shared hosting (in which people often lack root access to install the programs mentioned, even if they have SSH access). Many people searching for this answer, and perhaps the OP, will be on shared hosting, or want to compare it as an option. I'd have added this as a comment on the OP but couldn't, so alas it'll appear after all the other answers, rather than before where it might help someone in this position. Oh well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Apache Bench (ab)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) to test webserver performance

You can analyze `sar` reports (e.g. [sarcheck](http://www.sarcheck.com/)) to identify system bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing and running `HardInfo`. I use Ubuntu, so my package manager is APT, but on CentOS the relevant command might be something like

```
yum install hardinfo
```

Also, take a look at this [how-to](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Benchmarking-HOWTO.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Apache JMeter; you can use it to simulate high load on the web server, and it will give you useful stats.  You can customize web hits so it's not just a high-load spider crawl of the web server, but can perform exact actions such as click here, enter text, submit, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try `httperf`:

http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/

Combine it with `Ganglia`:

http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a very large infrastructure/IT department, Traverse is pretty neat -- http://www.zyrion.com/products/

It does dashboards, generates reports, and many other things. It even has an API for setting up your own tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'ab' (apache benchmark) to flood your webserver with requests.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a very simple option, but if you use Google Chrome as your browser, click view, developer tools. There is a nice tab in here for checking latency for elements and how fast they load, I've found this to be one of the best tools to see what part of a page is being delivered slowly.

As for server level monitoring, I've used Zenoss Core to monitor both the host and the application (IIS via WMI and Apache via the Nagios plug-in).

Answer (score 0):

I've used Pylot off and on, I like it being as you can program user behavior into it via simple XML.

http://www.pylot.org/